# Error on restoring Actor Backup - Method not found: 'Void System.Fabric.RestoreSettings..ctor(Boolean, Boolean)'

Tags: azure-service-fabric, service-fabric-actor

Trying to restore a backup for an ActorService and receiving the following error: `Method not found: 'Void System.Fabric.RestoreSettings..ctor(Boolean, Boolean)'`
There is no inner exception.

It is a custom actor service which Extends `ActorService` and Implements an interface which Extends `IActorService`

I have checked the backupFolder that's passed in and it is valid and has the backup within it. Given that it's restored I don't think it's relevant, but this is a backup that has been retrieved from Azure blob storage

This is the line the exception is thrown by:

`await restoreCtx.RestoreAsync(restoreRescription, cancellationToken);`

This is the method it sits within:

```
protected override async Task<bool> OnDataLossAsync(RestoreContext restoreCtx, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {

            try
            {
                string backupFolder;    

                backupFolder = await this.backupManager.RestoreLatestBackupToTempLocation(cancellationToken);                       

                RestoreDescription restoreRescription = new RestoreDescription(backupFolder, RestorePolicy.Force);

                await restoreCtx.RestoreAsync(restoreRescription, cancellationToken);    

                DirectoryInfo tempRestoreDirectory = new DirectoryInfo(backupFolder);
                tempRestoreDirectory.Delete(true);

                return true;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                ActorEventSource.Current.Message("Restoration failed: " + "{0} {1}" + e.GetType() + e.Message);

                throw;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Usually a Method not found exception is caused by using a version of the SF Nuget packages that is newer than the SF runtime they are running on. Check the SF runtime version you have installed and make sure the minor version is greater than or equal to the SF NuGet packages you're using. For example, the 5.4 runtime supports NuGet packages 2.4 and lower, but not 2.5.

Comment: @VaclavTurecek That did the trick, thanks very much, was the last hiccup stopping Actor backups from working!

Comment: Cool. This happens, btw, because at times we need to add new functionality to the runtime to support new features in the SDK. So we can't guarantee that a new version of one of the NuGet packages will always work on an older runtime. But you can always use the latest runtime without having to update your NuGet packages to match, they should continue to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by @VaclavTurecek the problem was that the Service Fabric Nuget packages were a version ahead of the runtime installed on the server (in this case my local machine). Updating via the Web Platform Installer has resolved the problem.